# How to count rows greater than a value and write the count to a text file in Linux

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file with sample data shown below:

```
%_above_10 %_above_20 %_above_30 %_above_50
88.6    88.1    87.8    87.2
89.1    78.5    72.3    59.4
100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0
100.0   100.0   100.0   100.0
100.0   100.0   70.0   80.0
100.0   100.0   100.0   80.0
100.0    31.9    26.8    17.4
00.0   96.0    77.3    43.3
68.8    65.9    63.6    57.1
```

I need to count the rows in each column which have value 100 and write it to a text file. The output could look like:

```
Totalrows %_above_10 %_above_20 %_above_30 %_above_50
   9        5            4          3         2
```

I am able to count one column at a time using the basic awk command:

```
awk -F "\t" '{if($1 == 100)print;}
```

Could anyone suggest a way to count the columns in the above specified way and write to a file using linux commands or script (awk). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk solution:

```
$ cat chas.awk
NR == 1 { hdr = $0; next }    
{
    a[1] += ($1 == 100) ? 1 : 0;
    a[2] += ($2 == 100) ? 1 : 0;
    a[3] += ($3 == 100) ? 1 : 0;
    a[4] += ($4 == 100) ? 1 : 0;
}
END { print "Totalrows", hdr; print (NR-1),a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4] }

$ awk -f chas.awk chas.txt
Totalrows %_above_10 %_above_20 %_above_30 %_above_50
9 5 4 3 2
```

Or a more general solution with respect to the number of columns:

```
NR == 1 { hdr = $0; cols = NF; next }

{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
      a[i] += ($i == 100) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

END {
    print "Totalrows", hdr
    printf (NR-1)
    for (i=1; i<=cols; ++i) {
      printf " " a[i]
    }
    print "" # add final newline
}
```

Comment: Gonna upvote as its pretty much the same as my answer and you posted first :)

Comment: Why would you want an array `a["tot"]` instead of just a variable `tot`? I think the latter would be clearer. Actually you don't need that at all, just use `NR-1`. Also awk arrays (and fields) start at 1 so your first loop should start at 1, not 0, and you don't need the `cols` variable, just us `NF`.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason I should have wanted such a thing, @EdMorton, shamefully enough. Very much appreciate the critiques / improvements.  For the `cols` variable, though, it's that I wasn't sure it was safe to use `NF` in the end block. Will that always be the value of `NF` for the last line of the file in whatever version of awk?

Comment: Yes, NF is safe to use in the END block, unlike $0 which is dependent on your flavor of awk.

Answer (score 3):

A way with awk and column.

```
awk 'NR==1{print "TotalRows "$0;next}
     {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]+=$i==100}
     END{print NR-1,a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}' file | column -t
```

More general

```
 awk 'NR==1{print "TotalRows "$0;next} 
      {a[0]++;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]+=$i==100}
      END{for(i=0;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s ",a[i];print t}' test | column -t
```

---

#### Output

```
TotalRows  %_above_10  %_above_20  %_above_30  %_above_50
9          5           4           3           2
```

Comment: can we replace printf with normal print in the general solution above to skip %s" in the printf statement?

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lane '$F[$_] == 100 and $c[$_]++ for 0 .. $#F }{ print $.-1, " @c"' < input
```

- `-l` adds a newline to `print`
- `-a` splits the input to the `@F` array
- for each line, the script goes over the records and adds 1 to the particular counter if it sees 100
- once the file ends, the counter is printed, preceded by the number of files read minus one (you don't count the header)